# No registered resource provider found for location 'eastus2' and API version '2018-01-01' for type 'storageAccounts/blobServices

Tags: java, azure, sdk

I tried both Java SDK and API, and getting below error while trying to create an alert rule for a container which locates on eastus2. I can not figure out where "API version '2018-01-01'" is coming from, on API call, I am using a different API version (2018-03-01).
I think something is doing this API call at the background (might be related with container since it's region is eastus2, I really do not know). I would be really appreciate if anyone helps.

```json
{

"code": "ResourceNotFound",

"message": "No registered resource provider found for location 'eastus2' and API version '2018-01-01' for type 'storageAccounts/blobServices'. The supported api-versions are '2023-05-01, 2023-04-01, 2023-01-01, 2022-09-01, 2022-05-01, 2021-09-01, 2021-08-01, 2021-06-01, 2021-05-01, 2021-04-01, 2021-02-01, 2021-01-01, 2020-08-01-preview, 2019-06-01, 2019-04-01, 2018-11-01, 2018-07-01, 2018-03-01-preview, 2018-02-01, 2017-10-01, 2017-06-01, 2016-12-01, 2016-05-01'. The supported locations are 'eastus, eastus2, westus, westeurope, eastasia, southeastasia, japaneast, japanwest, northcentralus, southcentralus, centralus, northeurope, brazilsouth, australiaeast, australiasoutheast, southindia, centralindia, westindia, canadaeast, canadacentral, westus2, westcentralus, uksouth, ukwest, koreacentral, koreasouth, francecentral, australiacentral, southafricanorth, uaenorth, switzerlandnorth, germanywestcentral, norwayeast, westus3, jioindiawest, swedencentral, qatarcentral, polandcentral, italynorth, israelcentral'. Activity ID: c379a2e1-9633-48b7-9b5a-4c9d7199a8dd."

}
```

I tried both Java SDK and API, getting same error in both as described above. I am expecting to create alert through any of them.

Please see below the code block:

```
Response orUpdateWithResponse
= azureResourceManager.diagnosticSettings()
.manager()
.serviceClient()
.getMetricAlerts()
.createOrUpdateWithResponse(storageResourceGroup, dto.getName(),
new MetricAlertResourceInner().withLocation(region)
.withDescription(dto.getDescription())
.withSeverity(3)
.withEnabled(true)
.withScopes(List.of("/subscriptions/" + subscriptionId + "/resourceGroups/"
+ storageResourceGroup + "/providers/Microsoft"
+ ".Storage/storageAccounts/" + accountName
+ "/blobServices/default/containers" + dto.getMetricOf()))
.withEvaluationFrequency(Duration.parse(dto.getEvaluationFrequency()))
.withWindowSize(Duration.parse(dto.getWindowSize()))
.withCriteria(new MetricAlertSingleResourceMultipleMetricCriteria().withAllOf(
List.of(new MetricCriteria().withName(dto.getName())
.withMetricName(dto.getMetricName())
.withTimeAggregation(
AggregationTypeEnum.fromString(dto.getTimeAggregation()))
.withOperator(operator)
.withThreshold(dto.getAlarmConditionThreshold()))))
.withActions(
azureActionsService.handleActions(subscriptionId, storageResourceGroup,
dto.getTopicName(), region, dto.getSendTo(), azureCredentials)),
Context.NONE);
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please check if the provider is registered? Here are the steps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-providers-and-types then try it again

Comment: Hi @ViniciusDeschamps, it (Microsoft.Storage) is already registered. "storageAccounts/blobServices" is under "Microsoft.Storage".

Comment: Does anyone know how I can change and specify the API version in my code of Java SDK to ensure that the correct version is being used?